# How to open links from terminal-logs in vs-code?

Tags: gnome-terminal, visual-studio-code

How can I configure the default ubuntu terminal to identify file locations in the logs (for example: stack-traces) and be able to open them in my current opened VSCode instance?

In MacOS, I configured Iterm2 to do that. I'm not sure how to do it on Ubuntu.

If it's not possible, is there other terminal that can do that on Ubuntu?

Comment: fyi, it works when you have a `file://` link.

Comment: What configuration is required to make them have a file:// link?